# removing sherlock action bar inside tab

Tags: android, hide, actionbarsherlock

I have a class DashBoardTasks that extends SherlockListActivity that has the following code:

```
public class DashBoardTasks extends SherlockListActivity
{
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_listview);

  ActionBar a = DashBoardTasks.this.getSupportActionBar();
    a.hide();
  (...)
}
```

What happens is my SherlockActionBar disappears. So far so good.

Now I have this class TabHostTasks:

```
public class TabHostTasks extends tabActivity
```

When I call DashBoardTasks inside TabHostTasks what happens is
 **a = null**
And the applicattion crashes!!!! Why? Why does it work outside the Tab but it crashes inside the tab ? I just what to Hide the actionbar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect when `TabActivity` displays activities within its content area, those activities don't have window features like `ActionBar`. Your `DashBoardTasks` activity doesn't have the `ActionBar`; `TabHostTasks` does.

Write a method in `TabHostTasks` to manipulate your `ActionBar`. You can call `getParent()` from `DashBoardTasks` and cast it to `TabHostTasks`, then call your method to hide the bar.

Also you may consider trying to implement your app with a tabbed `ActionBar` instead. (`TabActivity` is deprecated)